# Joomla PHP Mail vs. SMTP

Tags: smtp, joomla2.5, php

I've been asked to change all of our current Joomla sites from using PHP Mail to SMTP.

The background: we were recently compromised through a vulnerable component on one of our sites. We have a dedicated server, running CPanel. The hack involved a file being uploaded to one account, which had a file manager (with access to /home, ie. all other accounts). From there, another file was uploaded that began sending emails - not enough to catch with ease, but eventually enough to get our main server IP blacklisted. Because the main IP was blacklisted, many of our other sites (for which we also host email) were also blacklisted.

My argument (your comments/ideas on this are much appreciated!)

1. Changing to SMTP will not solve this instance

   - It would solve the issue of any vulnerable components where an email can be sent via a request spoof (ie. option=com_users?task=email&..., or something similar to that)
2. Because the hacker has access to the files in the account, they also have access to the configuration.php file, which holds the SMTP password in plain text. Access to this means they would also have access to the SMTP server.
3. The SMTP that we would be using is localhost, which doesn't solve the issue of our IP being blacklisted.

   - My first idea was to provision/setup SMTP on a separate IP (or server), but that can still be blacklisted if a site gets hacked.
   - The second idea was to provision each site a unique IP, so no one site can get the rest blacklisted.

So I'm a bit lost. Before we tackle the task of setting the mailing function to SMTP, testing each site (there's roughly 70, with varying components to test) I'd like to have a better idea of what's the best route, if any.

It seems that either setting in Joomla is insecure in the event of a compromised site, no?

Comment: Is the issue resolved? Is the server still sending the spam? If you resolve the issue and takle to prevent it from returning, I don't see why you should change all the sites to use SMTP over PHP Mail.

Comment: Not sending spam anymore, no. As far as sites being 100% secured, I can't guarantee it, so there's potential for it to happen again. I don't see the benefit either, I see more benefit in making sure the sites are secure, and not using vulnerable components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find where your server is blacklisted, and apply to be removed. Note: if any of the sites require payment to be de-listed, ignore them. [eg: SORBS] Nobody cares about extortionists, trust me. I was admin for several busy mail servers for the last few years.
2. If you're completely switching from PHP-based `mail()` on all sites, then disable the mail agent on the server. `mail()` simply submits to the MTA running on the server [usually Sendmail or Postfix] and if your server is compromised again they will still be able to spam out.
3. Yes, your SMTP credentials will be stored in a config file somewhere, but most instances the intruder won't even bother to look for them. They simply drop in a basic PHP script that calls `mail()` and that's it.
4. If mail service is at all important to you you should always monitor:

   1. [The reputation of your outbound server.](http://multirbl.valli.org/)
   2. The abuse mail for your domain. It will either be coming to abuse@yourdomain.com, or the abuse@ contact for whoever owns the IP address block.

Comment: #3 is a good one; I assumed otherwise, after looking at the extensiveness of the script (File Manager, MySQL connection, Joomla compromise tests, etc, etc, etc.). Didn't know about #4 either; I honestly don't think an ad agency should be a full IT shop, but we became liable in this instance.